# How to write an android OpenGL application in C and load it using ADB on a rooted phone?

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, opengl-es

I would like to write a userspace application written in `c` or `c++` using `OpenGL` and run it on an `Android` smartphone.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` I have these written:

```
android:label="Graphics/OpenGL ES/Compressed Texture"
android:label="Graphics/OpenGL ES/Cube Map"
android:label="Graphics/OpenGL ES/Frame Buffer Object"
android:label="Graphics/OpenGL ES/GLSurfaceView"
android:label="Graphics/OpenGL ES/OpenGL ES 2.0"
android:label="Graphics/OpenGL ES/Matrix Palette Skinning"
android:label="Graphics/OpenGL ES/Translucent GLSurfaceView"
```

I used [this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/opengl/9780321563835/hello-triangle-an-opengl-es-2dot0-example/ch02#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODAzMjE1NjM4MzUlMkZjaDAybGV2MXNlYzM=) tutorial but the header file is not founded, I couldn't found the `esUtil.h` file. which is included (`#include "esUtil.h"`) in most of the tutorials.

I assume that is the `.h` [file](http://opengles-book-samples.googlecode.com/svn-history/r53/trunk/LinuxX11/Common/esUtil.h). And to sum up the steps I want to do:

1. write a c/cpp code using OpenGL.
2. build it as an executable file `a.out`.
3. use `adb` to load it to the phone.
4. run `a.out` on the phone. (assuming I have rooted the phone)

Please note that ***I prefer not to use `glut` or `NDK`***

Comment: "*I don't want to use glut*" That's good, because you *can't use GLUT* on a phone. GLUT is for desktop OpenGL; you can't use GLUT for accessing OpenGL *ES*, which is the only OpenGL available on Android. Desktop GL and GL ES aren't the same thing.

Comment: You ***HAVE*** to use ***NDK***. The NDK contains the headers and libraries you need to compile anything that should run on an Android device. You can't do without them.

Comment: agree with @Jan Hudec. You MUST use NDK just because it containc C runtime (bionic) with MUST be linked to your app otherwise it will not run